# Where to specify credentials of the repository to GitLab ci/cd pipeline?

Tags: maven, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed the latest version of SonarQube in my system and successfully integrate the SonarQube with GitLab.

When I run GitLab CI/CD pipeline it shows an error as `Could not resolve dependencies for project` and `Authentication failed for https://example.com:7790/develop/application_name:401 Unauthorized`.

My question is how to remove the above error?
Where to specify authentication credentials?
Where to specify credentials of any repository?

Comment: Can you take a look at environment variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is similar to [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/not-authorized-to-access-sonarqube-using-gitlab-credential/37383), where [G. Ann Campbell](https://twitter.com/ganncampbell) mentions the  ALM integration settings:

> Your GitLab account isn’t already recognized by SonarQube, and you’re not being allowed to “sign up”
> [image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sonarsource/uploads/sscommunity/original/3X/a/9/a9d118ed9bac02181cf4456bc975c261240f8c6a.jpeg]

Then see also:

- [Sonarcube GitLab Integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/), to review said integration parameters (which you must have done).
- [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.5/analysis/gitlab-cicd/) to chekc the `SONAR_TOKEN` and `SONAR_HOST_URL` environment variables.